# Image file upload from view to controller parameters returning null in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, image, upload

I am trying to upload an image from users files and save it to the database in byte[] format. I have tried numerous tutorials and have search SO but all I've tried has not solved my problem.

**Problem**: When I debug my project for where I pass the image from the view to the controller, the file is remaining null each time.

Here is my code:

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Events", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }, FormMethod.Post, null))
  {
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayName("Image")

            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]          
public ActionResult Create(AddEventViewModel addviewmodel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string filename = "";
        byte[] bytes;
        int BytestoRead;
        int numBytesRead;

        if(file != null)
        {
            filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            bytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            BytestoRead = (int)file.ContentLength;
            numBytesRead = 0;

            while(BytestoRead > 0)
            {
                int n = file.InputStream.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, BytestoRead);
                if (n == 0) break;

                numBytesRead += n;
                BytestoRead -= n;
            }

            addviewmodel.Event_Image = bytes;
        }

        var e = new Event();
        var ep = new EventPerformance();

        UpdateEvent(e, addviewmodel);

        db.Event.Add(e);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(addviewmodel);
}
```

It is good to note that I am using View Models.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Oh very sorry didn't realise thanks for that. I always search with those and ended up writing them automatically.

Comment: [so] puts the most popular tag into the `<title>` element for search engines to find, and you can search for a tag by using `[tag]` in the search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone who finds this and has the same problem I finally found my mistake in the end. I was using partial views and mistakenly had 2 @using(Html.BeginForm).... within both views and once I removed one of them it was working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your htmlAttributes are in the wrong place - should be:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Events", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

See: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for more

Comment: Does Request.Files[0] have a value? And is this a normal post with a submit button (i.e. are you using ajax to post the form?)

Comment: Request.File count is 0 and file is null. However, I'm not 100% sure i understood your question....EDIT; yes it is a normal post with a submit button but it is part of a bigger form.

Comment: Hmm not sure then, sorry!